# Get Fields from object that are set

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following struct:

```
 public struct UserProp<T>
{
    private T val;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (T) this.val;
        }
        set
        {
            this.val= value;
            this.IsSet = true;
        }
    }

    public bool IsSet;


}
```

and a class that uses it:

```
public class MyClass
{
     private UserProp<string> FirstName;
     private UserProp<int> ID;
     ....
}
```

How can I get all of the fields of the object where IsSet is true? I was going to use reflection and cast the GetField value as a UserProp, but I wouldn't know the type for the generic. Essentially what I am looking for is: get all fields of MyClass of type UserProp (regardless of generic type) where IsSet is true.

Comment: I have to point out that you have a recursive property in that class there. It will likely cause a `StackOverflowException`..

Comment: Thanks, the real object has firstname, lastname, etc. I was just trying to be concise. Thanks for pointing it out though, I fixed it.

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Setting `this.Value` in the setter for `Value` will cause it to go into an infinite loop. You need a private backing field for it.

Comment: Thanks for catching that Simon, saved me a bunch of debug time later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I wouldn't know the type for the generic

You don't need to know what `T` is. Use the open generic type. Here's a hopefully correct example:

```
var myClass = new MyClass();

foreach (var fieldInfo in myClass.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    var fieldType = fieldInfo.FieldType;

    if (!fieldType.IsGenericType ||
        fieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof (UserProp<>))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ignoring {0} {1}", fieldType.Name, fieldInfo.Name);
        continue;
    }

    var fieldValue1 = fieldInfo.GetValue(myClass);
    var fieldInfo2 = fieldValue1.GetType().GetField("IsSet");
    var fieldValue2 = fieldInfo2.GetValue(fieldValue1);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}.IsSet has a value of {1}", fieldInfo.Name, fieldValue2);

    // You can check fieldValue2 and if true you now have "[a field] of
    // MyClass of type UserProp (regardless of generic type) where IsSet
    // is true". Loop until you get them all!
}
```

Given this definition of `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int z;
    private UserProp<string> FirstName;
    private UserProp<int> ID;

    public MyClass()
    {
        ID.Value = 5;
    }
}
```

Would yield this result:

```
Ignoring Int32 z
FirstName.IsSet has a value of False
ID.IsSet has a value of True
```

Comment: +1 note that if `UserProp` is `struct` this code forces [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) on each access to the field. As usual reflection can be cached or even converted into [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) and compiled if it is found that the code is slow.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov +1 I must confess that I read your first sentence in my head and thought "duh, that's unavoidable" but you're quite right about the compiled expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have extremely good reasons to use `struct` consider switching to `class` for your `UserProp`. Than you can have base class to use for shared properties:

```
public class UserProp
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsSet { get; set; }
}

public class UserProp<T> : UserProp
{
   private T val;
   public T Value...
}
```

This way you'll only need to reflect over fields and check for known `UserProp` type and value will be available with direct access after cast (instead of one more reflection to get value by name).

Comment: *Than you can have base class to use for shared properties* `struct`s can implement interfaces. Just put an interface on it.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - good point - interface is an option if OP wants to stick with `struct`. I'd personally avoid `struct` (especially mutable one as in OP's case) due to the fact it is value type and normally confuses everyone who tries to access/change value of such type. I'm afraid code that changes this struct-wrapped properties must be reviewed very  carefully to avoid modifying copy of the field instead of original one...

Comment: Thanks Alexei, I used a struct because I am dealing with 1000s of employee objects in active memory at a time (each with about 40 properties (that would be structs)) and I thought the benefit of having the values on the stack rather than the heap would improve performance.

Comment: @Mike - I'd strongly recommend to measure instead of "thought" to make performance decisions. I.e. you are ok with reflection which means you are boxing your structs on every access to `IsSet` which forces creation of new object on the heap each time...

Comment: @Mike *I thought the benefit of having the values on the stack rather than the heap would improve performance* [Lulwat](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This should work if you don't mind using the dynamic keyword:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
        var type = myclass.GetType();
        var fields = type.GetFields().Where(x => x.FieldType != null && x.FieldType.Name == "UserProp`1");

        foreach (var item in fields)
        {
            dynamic userProp = item.GetValue(myclass);
            Console.WriteLine(userProp.IsSet);
        }

        myclass.FirstName.Value = "Mark";

        foreach (var item in fields)
        {
            dynamic userProp = item.GetValue(myclass);
            Console.WriteLine(userProp.IsSet);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```